# How to plot ema from different time period? Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am unsure as to why this code does not work to reference and plot a 5min chart HMA 49. keep getting
line 13: Syntax error at input '5'.
I am stumped?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Paul

//Get Values

```
hma49 = hma(close,49)
hma9 = hma(close,9)
ema9 = ema(close,9)
5minhma49 = security(syminfo.ticker,5, hma(close,49))
t = tickerid(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot start a variable name with a digit.
See reference manual [Identifiers](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Identifiers.html)

You could change `5minhma49` to `min5hma49` for example, to make it compile properly.